# Java based open source Digital Assest Management system

Tags: java, content-management-system, opencms

we are working on a project which is CMS system in itself and will require to handle a lots of digital data like images,videos and other assets.
we are analysing the options to use any thrid party DAMS system build in java since we are working on same platform and have inclination to use the same platform product.

do any one have good refrences to open source DAMS in java which can help us to manage our digital assests.

Thansk in advance

Comment: Is the CMS already implemented using OpenCms, since you tagged the question with it? Which features of a DAMS do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some pointers:

- [DSpace](http://www.dspace.org/) Focus on research and science
- [EnterMedia](http://entermediasoftware.com/) Many file formats, extensible
- [Fedora Commons](http://www.fedora-commons.org/) More a framework than a product

This list is not complete, for a good overview take a look at http://www.opensourcedigitalassetmanagement.org/reviews/available-open-source-dam/

Answer (score 2):

We are using Fedora Commons. It is a digital repository, which means that it does what you are asking, but is intended for long-term digital preservation and doesn't come with a front end that you would want general public to use.

We're currently working on a new project to use a Drupal module called "Islandora" which will turn Drupal into a dandy frontend. So far, so good. Your requirements may require no frontend or less of one, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I have personal experience with EnterMedia, and reckon it would be the ideal solution for your needs.  It is written in Java and is quite flexible and extensible.  Just going via the groovy script and openedit interfaces, you can probably achieve most of your needs for customization.  But, I am sure you can even avoid using OpenEdit if that falls outside your scope.

`The reason I would recommend EnterMedia over Alfresco ?`

- EnterMedia is focused on digital accept management functions primarily (rather than as a bolt on to a DMS like Alfresco is) ..
- You can get up and running much faster with Entermedia.
- EnterMedia is a very flexible system you can customize even without writing code, or by writing or modify existing groovy scripts.